# removing duplicate profiles loaded from an xml file using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am creating an app that loads an XML file with a list of profiles from the web. There is a button that shows all the profiles in a textView when pressed.

Now I want to have another button to remove duplicate profiles from that list on the textView, any help on how to do that is appreciated!

**I have a:**

NSMutableDictionary *profileDict;

NSMutableArray *profile;

NSArray *profileArr;

I have researched on how to do it but couldn't find something that was related to what I need. I have read something about NSPredicate but I am new to it and don't know how to make it work on my project.

Here is the code for the button that displays the profiles in the textView:

```
- (IBAction)showProfilesButton:(id)sender
{
    XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init]; //This is loading the XMLParser class
    [parser loadXML];

    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSMutableDictionary *obj in [[Globals globalBinding]globalArr])
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", [obj objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
    }
    [self.profilesLabelTextView setText:str];
}
```

IBAction for removing the duplicates:

```
- (IBAction)removeDuplicates:(id)sender
{
    //How should I start here.....?
}
```

**EDIT: THE REST OF THE CLASSES TO SUPPORT THE QUESTIONS**

Underneath I have put the rest of the classes to make everything clear.

***XMLParser.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface XMLParser : NSObject

{
    bool isStatus;
    XMLParser *currentProfile;
    XMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray *profile;
    NSString *firstName;
}

- (void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;
- (void)loadXML;

- (NSString *)firstName;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *profileDict;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *profile;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *profileArr;

@end
```

***XMLParser.m***

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Globals.h"

@implementation XMLParser
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    self.profileDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.profile=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.profileArr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [XMLParser alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {

        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
    //    NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
        [self.profileDict setObject:currentProfile->firstName forKey:@"firstname"];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profile"])
    {
        [self.profile addObject:self.profileDict];
        self.profileDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [[Globals globalBinding]setGlobalArr:self.profile];
    }
}

-(void)loadXML
{
    [self loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
}

-(NSString *)firstName
{
    return firstName;
}

@end
```

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *profilesLabelTextView;

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Globals.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
 - (IBAction)removeDuplicates:(id)sender
{
}

//Code for the button to display the profiles
- (IBAction)showProfilesButton:(id)sender
{
    XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
    [parser loadXML];

    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSMutableDictionary *obj in [[Globals globalBinding]globalArr])
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", [obj objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
    }

    [self.profilesLabelTextView setText:str];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

***Global.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Globals : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *globalArr;
+(Globals*)globalBinding;

@end
```

***Global.m***

```
#import "Globals.h"
static Globals *global=nil;

@implementation Globals

+(Globals*)globalBinding
{
    if (global == nil) {
        global = [[Globals alloc]init];
    }
    return global;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the format of your data, it's impossible to answer. However, a general answer is to use the key path operator "distinctUnionOfObjects."

For example, if you have a list of strings that you wish to parse.

```
NSArray* array = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"B"];
NSArray* uniqueValues = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];

// will results in uniqueValues array containing A, B, C
```

Or if you have an array with objects, and those objects each have a property (such as a "name") you wish to make unique, you could do the following.

```
NSArray* uniqueValues = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

Without knowing more about your dictionary or your object structure, I'm afraid we can't get more detailed than that.

And frankly, this is just one of the many ways to skin the proverbial cat. It's applicable for simple data and data structures, but can break down as things get more complicated.

Edit:

To handle your specifics, use the following example. As you can see, it grabs distinct first names from an array containing dictionaries, each with a "firstname" item.

```
NSDictionary* dict1 = @{ @"firstname" : @"A" };
NSDictionary* dict2 = @{ @"firstname" : @"B" };
NSDictionary* dict3 = @{ @"firstname" : @"C" };
NSDictionary* dict4 = @{ @"firstname" : @"A" };

NSArray* array = @[ dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4 ];

NSLog(@"Distinct Values = %@", [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.firstname"]);
// prints out "Distinct Values = (A, B, C)"
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, I have added the rest of the classes so you can see the data format etc.. I hope you can understand it now. Thanks

Comment: What is your end result? An NSMutableArray containing a list of NSDictionaries, each with a single entry, firstname?

Comment: Yes, and I want to be able to remove duplicate first names, for example if there are 2 John's in the list I want to remove one..

Comment: Hi Travis, can you please help me out with this, I tried everything but getting no luck so far.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I've been away. At any rate, you can easily extend the example I gave to get a distinct list. Here's a bit of sample code.

    NSDictionary* dict1 = @{ @"firstname" : @"A" };
    NSDictionary* dict2 = @{ @"firstname" : @"B" };
    NSDictionary* dict3 = @{ @"firstname" : @"C" };
    NSDictionary* dict4 = @{ @"firstname" : @"A" };
    
    NSArray* array = @[ dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4 ];
    
    NSLog(@"Values = %@", [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.firstname"]);

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help! I managed to fix a bit of the problem by using NSSet, check the edit2 above. Now my problem is: each profile contains: first name, lastname, email etc. This is still not showing up properly for some reason I don't know why, maybe you can see the problem?